# Popup for android or iphone tot download app when visiting site

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, popup

) We have in app for android and iphone. When someone visits are website using their mobile phone, we want i popup that says.. Hi we have an app, want to download it? or whatever ;-) When selected yes, it has to download the app.

But i only want the popup to display when the app is not yet installed... So far i found this code.. As you can see, this wont work.. If anyone could help me out! Would be great!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if( /Android|iPhone|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  var url=confirm("Would you like to download our mobile application?");
    if (url==true)
  {
    var url = window.location.href = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?    id=com.appmachine.p9890BH';
url.show(); 
  }
    else
  {

  }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You want a web page to be able to read what apps a user has installed?  Really?  Do you think this might be a security/privacy problem?  I don't know iOS, but on Android, this is not possible.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for that insight. If that is a problem, we need the code without that bit. So only if android, it should show download popup for play store, and for iphone a dwonload for itunes.

Answer (score 4):

For the iPhone, promoting your app while checking for its existence is possible with Apple's smart app banner, [here are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html).

This is limited to Apple and Safari, but it's a good starting spot.

Otherwise, I used [this library](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js) and it has worked pretty well out of the box for me so far..

Comment: Thanks Riley, smartBanner.js does the dirty job quick and smoothly!